# Problem with showModalDialog javascript function in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am having a parent page from which I am opening another page in a modal popup window using "showModalDialog" javascript function, the page is opening correctly in a modal popup window, but the problem is that, when I click on any `<aspx:Button>` in the modal popup page, the page again gets opened in a new browser window, while in the modal popup window, it is still open.

Any body knows why this is happening ?

I have also attached a sample solution for this containing the least amount of code required to produce the problem:

http://rapidshare.com/files/435608108/ShowModalDialogProblem.rar

Any other way to solve this problem is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following in the `<head>` section of your aspx page:

```
<base target=_self>
```

Comment: I found this line somewhere on net, but didn't give attention to it. Thanks a lot!!